# Converting VB 6 code to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am upgrading code from VB 6 to VB.NET, and the following code gives me an error:

```
(VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(mvarPicture.ClientRectangle.Width) - (BDR + X), 
VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPicture.ClientRectangle.Height) - (BDR + X)),
mvarBorderColor,
B
```

The error is:

> Error 6 End of statement expected.

Can anyone help me with that?

---

This is the full code:

```
Public Sub Draw()
    Dim BDR, X As Short
    Dim NewX, NewY As Double
    Dim OldX, OldY As Double
    Dim GridHeight, GridWidth As Double
    Dim mvarPictureBox As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox



    On Error GoTo NoPicBox ' In case the PicBox isn't set yet

    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox property mvarPictureBox.AutoRedraw was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
    If mvarPicture.AutoRedraw = False Then mvarPicture.AutoRedraw = True
    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox method mvarPictureBox.Cls was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
    mvarPicture.Cls()

    BDR = mvarPictureBox.BorderStyle
    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox property mvarPictureBox.ScaleMode was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
    If mvarPicture.ScaleMode <> 3 Then mvarPicture.ScaleMode = 3
    If System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(mvarPictureBox.BackColor) <> System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(mvarPicBackground) Then mvarPictureBox.BackColor = mvarPicBackground
    If mvarBorderSize > 0 Then
        For X = 0 To mvarBorderSize
            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox method mvarPictureBox.Line was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
            mvarPicture.Line (X, X) - (VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(mvarPicture.ClientRectangle.Width) - (BDR + X), VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPicture.ClientRectangle.Height) - (BDR + X)), mvarBorderColor, B
        Next X
    End If

    ' Display Grid On Screen
    If mvarGridVisible = True Then
        For X = 1 To 20
            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox method mvarPictureBox.Line was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
            mvarPicture.Line (mvarBorderSize, mvarBorderSize) - ((((VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) / 20) * X), (VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (mvarBorderSize * 2))), mvarGridColor, B
        Next X
        For X = 1 To 10
            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox method mvarPictureBox.Line was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
            mvarPicture.Line (mvarBorderSize, mvarBorderSize) - ((VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)), (((VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) / 10) * X)), mvarGridColor, B
        Next X
    End If

    If mvarDataCollection.Count() > 0 Then
        GridHeight = ((VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) / 100) + 0 ' 0-100%
        GridWidth = ((VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) / 100) + 0 ' 1-100 Items
        Do
            If mvarDataCollection.Count() > 100 Then mvarDataCollection.Remove(1)
        Loop While mvarDataCollection.Count() > 100

        OldX = mvarBorderSize + 2
        'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object mvarDataCollection(). Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
        OldY = ((VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) - (mvarDataCollection.Item(1) * GridHeight))
        For X = 1 To 100
            NewX = (VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) - ((100 - (X - 1)) * GridWidth)
            'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object mvarDataCollection(). Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
            NewY = ((VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(mvarPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (mvarBorderSize * 2)) - (mvarDataCollection.Item(X) * GridHeight))
            NewX = NewX + 2
            If NewX < mvarBorderSize Then NewX = mvarBorderSize
            If NewY < mvarBorderSize Then NewY = mvarBorderSize

            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: PictureBox method mvarPictureBox.Line was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
            mvarPicture.Line (OldX, OldY) - (NewX, NewY), mvarPicForeground


            OldX = NewX : OldY = NewY
            If OldX < mvarBorderSize Then OldX = mvarBorderSize
            If OldY < mvarBorderSize Then OldY = mvarBorderSize
        Next X
    End If

NoPicBox:
End Sub
```

Comment: Lets have the code again, together with a couple of lines above and below...

Comment: Dim BDR, X As Short
        Dim NewX, NewY As Double
        Dim OldX, OldY As Double
        Dim GridHeight, GridWidth As Double
        Dim mvarPictureBox As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox

Comment: That is not valid VB6 code either.  If you want to break a long statement across multiple lines then you must use an underscore _ at the end of the line.

Comment: Simple answer; you are missing close paren(s) at the end of those lines.  There is a huge disparity in open/close parens in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you're missing opening and closing parentheses on those lines.

Long answer, `PictureBox.Line()` is not supported in VB.NET.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dtfzwyx(v=vs.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawline(v=vs.90).aspx for how to do it in .NET.